# Mobile journaling app for data collection from participants in a research project

Tags: android, ios

I am looking for a "FREE" mobile journaling/diary application to be used during the data collection of a small-scale research project.
The application has to meet the following requirements:

1. It should have similar functionality and user interface on both Android 2.3+ and iOS (iPad is not a must).
2. All the following functionality must be free of charge (i.e., it shouldn't require a pro version).
3. It should automatically add a timestamp to the user entry.
4. It should be able to record text and images. Location and sound recordings would be great, too, but these features are not indispensible.
5. It should have an automatic sync feature.
6. It should be able to export the whole data to send an email. Since the researchers should be able to access the copies of these data, they must be accessible from desktop, because at some point we will need to have them on desktop to analyze them. I mean, we should have an easy access to user data (only read, not write).
7. It should have password protection option because the data are private.
   If there is no free app that meets the requirements above, we would like to purchase a number of licenses to our users (Like being able to purchase 40 licenses for a list of accounts, so that we don't ask our users to pay for it).